# Using Repr to change units

Tags: python, beagleboneblack

I am new to StackOverflow and am happy to be here! I am currently working with my beaglebone black and making a program to basically everytime detect a change in one of my input pins in a duration of time, in this case 2 minutes, to record it in a file, and I wanted to represent it in milliseconds. However, when using the repr() line in my code, I always get a syntax error in this line. After some research, I realized that repr() turns it into a string. Is the error stemming from not being able to understand the number and it does not turn it into a string? How would you be able in this case to convert time? Any lead into the right direction is greatly appreciated, sorry if anything is out of place or not in the rules of the forum :).

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setup("P8_9",GPIO.IN)
x = time.time()
t_end = time.time()+60 * 2

GPIO.add_event_detect("P8_9", GPIO.RISING)

while time.time() < t_end:
        if(GPIO.event_detected("P8_9")):
                f = open("/var/lib/cloud9/Timestamp.txt","a")
                millis = int(round(time.time()*10000)
                f.write(int(repr(millis)))
                f.write("\n")
                f.close
print("Done!")
```

Comment: Why are you converting `millis`, which is already an integer, to a string and then to an integer again? You can just convert it to a string when you write it -> `f.write(str(millis))`

Comment: Great point, I did not realize that until you told me, thanks so much man! But, still with the string it still is giving me a syntax error, could it just be that it doesn't understand the number and doesn't convert it to a string?